# Creating a key-value pair dynamically and then... and then

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible to create a key-value pair from an HTML radio button and text box value, then insert that pair into an array, then pass that array into a SQL Stored Procedure parameter that adds to the WHERE clause in the SP?

I am building a dashboard app that references one table in the SQL Server DB when it starts. This brings back the results of a simple select SP. I am pretty new to SQL so I am "psuedo-coding"(sorry)

```
   DECLARE @SelectedDate NVARCHAR(50)       
   SELECT * FROM Tablename WHERE log_ts > @SelectedDate
```

However at this point I need to be able to select between 1-4 field names and give them a value to filter by.

I would love to set up those field names as a radio button, and to prevent injection, screen those inputs against known values in my application before sending them to the server, including inserting default values of the input is null. 
My thought was to set up an array[string, string] once the screening is done, and pass that array into SQL as an array[field, value].(there would never be a null value).Here is what i would like the array to look like when being sent and all pairs are their default values:

```
   QueryArray = ["application_name","Mobile"]
                ["login_id","*"]
                ["log_ts","Datetime.Today"]
                ["error_level","Exception"]
```

Then somehow pass it into the where clause like this:

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM TableName
   WHERE [application_name] = [Mobile]
     AND [login_id]=[*]
     AND [log_ts]=[Datetime.Today] 
     AND [error_level]=[Exception]
```

This is where my brain looks normally for a for-each or something, but SQL if pretty new to me... Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if its just a link to a previous article that I could not find...

Comment: You could try this approach as for your last statement `SELECT f1,fn FROM TABLE WHERE f1 in ('v1') and f2 in ('v2')`. But I am still trying to fully understand your requirements. Will think about it a bit more.

Comment: You need to show us examples of your data and what you want returned. If you are comparing dates you should use `DateTime` not `NVARCHAR`. You also need to tell us what you want when `field2` does not exist.

Comment: Also thought about using Entity Framework as an abstraction layer for your database workload?

Comment: i edited to show the default values, so there will never be a null value passed into the DB. 85% of the time the user will only be passing in one key-value pair at a time, but to save connections to the DB, i wan tthem to be able to pass all 4

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/22437/dour-high-arch I am using an nvarchar because i dont have to convert the string entered by the user into a SQL datetime format. I check in my app to ensure it will parse, but then pass it in as a string to the DB so the db can parse into the format it prefers for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use nullable parameters in conjunction with the coalesce operator. This works well if you have a known set of parameters, and then want to filter against them. So if you know all the possible fields you can search on, *which is assuming you know ahead what fields you will display on your UI for people to filter with*, then you can actually make a procedure like so:

```
create procedure [dbo].[MySampleProcedure]
    @Property1Value <yourDataType> = null,
    @Property2Value <yourDataType> = null,
    ....
as
begin
     select
          Col1,
          Col2,
          ...
     from
         [dbo].[YourTable]
     where
         Column1Value = coalesce(@Property1Value, Column1Value)
         and Column2Value = coalesce(@Property2Value, Column2Value)
         ....
end
```

This effectively means that if you omit certain parameters, you can still match based on the parameters you provide. When you receive your set from the UI, you can then match the pairs to parameters and you're off to the races.

If your field names are dynamic (not known ahead of time), then it becomes a more difficult issue. In that case, you will likely have to drop to dynamic SQL to accomplish what you want, and construct a query using parameterized SQL, to avoid injection attempts.

Comment: Am I understanding that instead of passing the array of key-value to the sql, i can just pass the parameters of each field, and allow those parameters to be null.  so i would always pass the 4 parameters in, in the same order.